# FPC: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Tags: c++, pascal

I have something that need to link some C++ codes to main Pascal program. I followed this [tutorial](http://bbs.2ccc.com/attachments/2017/hawke2e_201781623924.pdf), now I have:

download.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;

// function goes here
int downloadsrc(char* pkg_name){
   // do stuff
}
```

download.pas:

```
unit download;
{$link download.obj} // fpc may overwrite download.o
Interface
uses ctypes;
function downloadsrc(pkg_name:string):integer;
Implementation
// I leave this empty
end.
```

My main program:

```
program myprog;
uses
    warn, download, test;
var i:integer;
begin
    if ParamCount = 0 then help()
    else for i:= 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
       if ParamStr(i) = 'download' then downloadsrc(ParamStr(i+1))
       else if ParamStr(i) = 'test' then test();
    end;
end.
```

I tried g++ to compile .h file, change the output.. but when build the program FPC says that:

```
download.obj: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

Compiling download.pas manually still works.
Am I do something wrong here? Am I need to do some other things, like add a compile flag or modify the code?

Comment: Note that C and C++ header files typically only contain declarations of functions, not their implementations. Those should be in `.c` or `.cpp` files and it's those files which get compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPC, like GCC, uses COFF objects. Make sure your .obj is COFF not OMF.

If you fix that, you probably must also link some C++ runtime library, and declare downloadsrc in a C callable way, and alter the FPC declaration to match (cdecl)